# Why is my UICollectionViewCell not getting data from UICollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewController` called `SwipingController` that creates a `TeamCell` and gives it a `teamName` of "Boston Celtics"

```
class SwipingController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView?.register(TeamCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! TeamCell

        cell.teamName = "Boston Celtics"

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code, `teamName` still prints out as an empty string.

```
class TeamCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var teamName: String =  ""

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        print(teamName) //this prints nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: You get blank screen now ?

Comment: @YogeshPatel No, I get my CollectionViewCells on the screen. The problem is, the `teamName` in the TeamCell is an empty string even though I set it equal to "Boston Celtics" in `SwipingController()`

Comment: please assign constrain to your label then it show you.

Answer (score 3):

`let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! TeamCell`

it inits the cell, and so initially it is empty.

After initialization `cell.teamName = "Boston Celtics"` is called, actually having no effect

you have to update the name

```
class TeamCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var teamName: String =  ""

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        print(teamName) //this prints nothing
    }

    func updateName(name : String) {
         self.testName = name

    }

}
```

in collectionview

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! TeamCell

        cell.updateName(name : "Boston Celtics") 

        return cell
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this :

```
class TeamCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var teamName : String = "" {
       didSet {
           print(teamName)
       }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       //custom logic goes here

    }
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! TeamCell

    cell.teamName = "Boston Celtics"

    return cell
}
```

OR

```
class TeamCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       //custom logic goes here

    }

    func getTeamName(teamName : String)
    {
        print(teamName)
    }
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! TeamCell

    cell.getTeamName(teamName: "Boston Celtics")

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are simply looking at `teamName` too early in the process. By the time `cellForItemAt` hits the `cell.teamName = ...` line, the cell’s `init` method has already been called. So, `teamName` will always be blank during the `init` method. But, `teamName` will be set before the cell appears within the view.

---

Often cells would just have UIKit controls, such as a `UILabel`, and you’d set the `text` of that, e.g.

```
class TeamCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var teamLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configure() {
        addSubview(teamLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            teamLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            teamLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func update(for team: String) {
        teamLabel.text = team
    }
}
```

And then

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! TeamCell

    cell.update(for: "Boston Celtics")

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in TeamCell class try this

```
var teamcell = String()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    if teamcell != nil {
        print(teamName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s just a matter of order of events. The cell is created, you print, the cell is used in the table view, the team name is assigned.